# vb.net Is there a faster way to substract one list of string from another

Tags: vb.net, string, list

```
Public done As New List(Of String)
Public thinkingofdoing As New List(Of String)
Public todo As New List(Of String)

done.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Work\Desktop\done.txt"))
thinkingofdoing.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Work\Desktop\thinkingofdoing.txt"))

For i = 0 To thinkingofdoing.Count - 1
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf caldiff, thinkingofdoing(i))
Next

Public Sub caldiff(ByVal tobedone)
    If done.Contains(tobedone) = False Then
        todo.Add(tobedone)
    End If
End Sub
```

**done.txt** and **thinkingofdoing.txt** have anywhere from 5 million to 8 million lines

It's taking very long :(, even with a quad core AMD 965 overclocked to 4.2 GHZ.

Comment: You are using the thread pool with non-thread safe collections. Fixing that won't fix your performance, but it will probably prevent subtle bugs later down the line.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the above code is not valid.  `List(Of T)` is not thread safe, so doing this from multiple threads will actually cause significant problems without synchronization, as the calls to `Add` and `Contains` aren't themselves safe to be called from multiple threads.

A better option would be to choose better collections, such as `HashSet(Of T)`, which would cause the checks to be far faster.  I would recommend something like:

```
public Done as New HashSet(Of String)
public ThinkingOfDoing as IList(Of String) 
public Todo as New List(Of String)

ThinkingOfDoing = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Work\Desktop\thinkingofdoing.txt")
Done.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Work\Desktop\done.txt"))

ToDo = ThinkingOfDoing.Where(Function(i) Done.Contains(i) = False).ToList()
```

By using a `HashSet(Of T)`, the `Contains()` check will become far faster (`O(1)` instead of `O(n)`), which will cause this to run a *lot* faster, even single threaded.

If you don't need to *store* Done, you could just keep the array, and use `Enumerable.Except` directly (which uses a Set internally):

```
ThinkingOfDoing = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Work\Desktop\thinkingofdoing.txt")
Dim done = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Work\Desktop\done.txt")

Dim Todo = ThinkingOfDoing.Except(done).ToList();
```

Comment: The last bit of code sorted everything. What was probably going to take 15-20 hours was completed in 15 seconds. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) which should be much more efficient because it's implemented as`HashSet<T>` :

```
IEnumerable(Of String) newLines = thinkingofdoing.Except(done)
```

You should also use `File.ReadLines` instead of `File.ReadAllLines` since the former uses streams whereas the latter loads all into memory at once.

I would test the performance without using `ThreadPool` first.

Answer (score 0):

how about this ...

```
Public done As ISet(Of String) 
Public toDo As New List(Of String)(); 

done = New HashSet(Of String) _
    (System.IO.File.ReadAllLine("C:\Users\Work\Desktop\done.txt")

Using reader As New StreamReader(New FileStream _
        ("C:\Users\Work\Desktop\thinkingofdoing.txt"), FileMode.Open)
    Do While reader.Peek() >= 0
        Dim line = reader.ReadLine()
        If Not done.Contains(line) Then
            toDo.Add(line)
        EndIf
    Loop
End Using
```

This loads all the done lines into a HashSet which has excellent lookup performance, then instead of loading the whole of the thinking of doing file into memory it gets parsed line by line and only added to todo if it is not already in done.

If VB.Net had a yield return I would have put that in a function and done ToList on the IEnumerable but hey ho.